# Why does this simple SVG animation work in FF but not Chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome, animation, svg

I have been experimenting with looping backgrounds for various SVG animation purposes. This particular experiment was done to symbolise rainfall, but, unfortunately, I have not been able to get this rendering correctly in Chrome -- although, it seems to work fine in Firefox.

[demo](https://codepen.io/shytiger/pen/aReByj)

Can anyone tell me why it isn't working in Chrome and what, if anything, can be done to fix it.

I have created a rain effect in the past using another method (background image), but I would like to try/learn a pure SVG/CSS approach, if possible.

```css
   .wrapper{
      width:200px;
      border:1px solid red;
    }

    .rain{
      animation: rain-xy 2s linear infinite;
    }

    @keyframes rain-xy{
      0%{transform:translate(0px,0px);}
      100%{transform:translate(-100px,100px);}
    }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
      <svg version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <g class="rain" fill="#484592">
          <circle cx="18.81" cy="16.61" r="4.407"/>
          <circle cx="71.19" cy="80.17" r="4.407"/>
          <circle cx="61.53" cy="45.76" r="4.407"/>
          <circle cx="20.34" cy="80.34" r="4.407"/>
          <circle cx="73.05" cy="18.47" r="4.407"/>
          <circle cx="25.25" cy="47.97" r="4.407"/>
          <circle cx="118.8" cy="16.61" r="4.407"/>
          <circle cx="171.2" cy="80.17" r="4.407"/>
          <circle cx="161.5" cy="45.76" r="4.407"/>
          <circle cx="120.3" cy="80.34" r="4.407"/>
          <circle cx="173.1" cy="18.47" r="4.407"/>
          <circle cx="125.3" cy="47.97" r="4.407"/>
          <circle cx="118.8" cy="-83.39" r="4.407"/>
          <circle cx="171.2" cy="-19.83" r="4.407"/>
          <circle cx="161.5" cy="-54.24" r="4.407"/>
          <circle cx="120.3" cy="-19.66" r="4.407"/>
          <circle cx="173.1" cy="-81.53" r="4.407"/>
          <circle cx="125.3" cy="-52.03" r="4.407"/>
          <circle cx="18.81" cy="-83.39" r="4.407"/>
          <circle cx="71.19" cy="-19.83" r="4.407"/>
          <circle cx="61.53" cy="-54.24" r="4.407"/>
          <circle cx="20.34" cy="-19.66" r="4.407"/>
          <circle cx="73.05" cy="-81.53" r="4.407"/>
          <circle cx="25.25" cy="-52.03" r="4.407"/>
        </g>
      </svg>
  </div>
```

Comment: It works fine for me on both browsers. Can you be specific on the version?
Chrome version: Version 70.0.3538.77 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: @ToanLu It seems like I was using an old version of Chromium I downloaded the latest version of Chrome and it looks to be working. I am a little concerned that there may be people that won't see my animations as they are intended. Also, adding the webkit vendor prefix didn't seem to help.

Comment: @Kaiido My mistake, the code shown here did not match the demo. I have amended it now. The problem was the circles moved but they were glitching.

Comment: @Kaiido I checked out the pen link.  <br/>@BumblingBadger Currently, not many browsers yet support `transform` & some other effects on SVG. https://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-html

Comment: @ToanLu my (obsolete) comment was pointing out a typo in the code snippet, where the class in the doc and in the css were not matching. Op's code should work in Chrome since numerous versions of the browser, but they indeed have an habit of landing new bugs every now and then. Probably what OP faced with their previous version.